# Weird integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I was thinking about $\int_{a}^{b} x! dx$ and the first thought I had was that it made no sense because, the factorial is only defined for natural numbers but they are also defined by the Gamma function right?

So, my question is when does $\int_{a}^{b} x! dx$  make sense? And how would you compute the integral in the cases where it makes sense? (what if a or b $\rightarrow \pm \infty$?)

On the other hand, since this integral seemed pretty weird to me, I wanted to know what other odd/strange/weird integrals are there that you know of?

Comment: It would probably make sense whenever $x!$ is indeed defined by $\Gamma(x+1)$, and whenever $a>-1, b<\infty$ (since it will "blow up" at those points). At least for real-valued integrals anyhow.

Comment: *whenever $a> -1$

Comment: Right, my bad. I'll edit that.

Comment: Another oddity: $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \sin(x)\sin(x^2) \ \text{d}x$ converges!  And something to ponder whose answer I don't know: does $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty | \sin(x) \sin(x^2) | \ \text{d}x$ converge?

Comment: @KajHansen Wow! That's interesting.

Comment: @KajHansen How do you get the convergence of the first integral?

Comment: @user209663, tbh, I don't know a rigorous proof.  The sign of the function changes increasingly frequently due to that $x^2$, so there's a lot of cancellation, and those pieces added / subtracted "generally" get increasingly small, so its reminiscent to me of the convergence of an alternating series whose terms approach zero.  Someone told me this fact long ago and it blew me away; don't know how to prove it, but I checked on Mathematica / Wolfram and [it agrees](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E%5Cinfty+sin(x)sin(x%5E2)).